# What's Wrong with this Request to the WeatherApi

Tags: javascript, node.js, web

it is about a weather app that im learn about it and i have a problem so can u help me in it

**it's giving error when it takes the id
I left a comment in the place where the error is please check it out
and thanks**

```
const form = document.querySelector("form");
const input = document.querySelector("input");
const div = document.querySelector("div")


    window.addEventListener("load", ()=>{
        let lat;
        let long;
        
        if(navigator.geolocation){
            navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(position =>{
                lat = position.coords.longitude;
                long = position.coords.latitude;
                let id;
                const apiSearchByLat_Long = `https://cors-anywhere.herokuapp.com/https://www.metaweather.com/api/location/search/?lattlong=${long},${lat}`
                console.log(long)
                console.log(lat)
                
                
            fetch(apiSearchByLat_Long)
                .then(response =>{
                    return response.json();
                })
                .then(data =>{
                    id = data[0].woeid
                    console.log(id);

                })
                
     const apiSearchById = `https://cors-anywhere.herokuapp.com/https://www.metaweather.com/api/location/${id}/`
         fetch(apiSearchById)
//the error is here it tells me "https://cors-anywhere.herokuapp.com/https://www.metaweather.com/api/location/undefined/"
                .then(response =>{
                    return response.json();
                })
                .then(data =>{
                    console.log(data)
                })
        
       })
        
        
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks like id is assigned in a promise, but the promise isn't resolved. You can make the callback function for window.addEventListener() async and then prepend all fetch() calls with the await keyword.

Answer (score 0):

Hey there the only thing I can figure out is that you are probably passing an undefined id to the weather api please check out the documentation or share a link in the comments for me to have a look at it .
Thanks happy coding

Answer (score 0):

Thanks guys for the help but I figured it.
The answer was to take the second fetch and put it in ".then"